# No Adapter Attached RecyclerView

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to implement my app. My app went smoothly, but I also got an error with 2022-05-31 14:14:32.663 8626-8626/id.kotlin.belajar E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout; skipping layout.

[E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout; skipping layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LECmO.png)

Home Activity:

```
class HomeActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity(), HomeView {
@Inject
  lateinit var presenter: HomePresenter

  private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
  private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

      progressBar = findViewById(R.id.pb_home)
      recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_home)

      presenter.discoverMovie()
  }

  override fun onShowLoading() {
      progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
  }
  override fun onHideLoading() {
      progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
      recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
  }

  override fun onResponse(results: List<Result<String>>) {
      recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this@HomeActivity, 
  DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
      recyclerView.adapter = HomeAdapter(results)
  }

  override fun onFailure(t:Throwable) {
      Log.e(HomeActivity::class.java.simpleName, "${t.printStackTrace()}")
  }
}
```

Home Adapter:

```
class HomeAdapter (private val results: List<Result>): 
RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder>(){

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HomeViewHolder {
      return HomeViewHolder(
          LayoutInflater
              .from(parent.context).inflate(
                  R.layout.item_home,
                  parent,
                  false
              )
      )
  }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HomeViewHolder, position: Int){
      holder.bind()
  }
  override fun getItemCount(): Int{
      return results.count()
  }

  inner class HomeViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
      fun bind() {
          with(itemView) {
              val title = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.original_title)
              title.text

              val overview = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.overview)
              overview.text
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Home Presenter:

```
 class HomePresenter(private val view: HomeView, datasource: HomeDatasource) {
  fun discoverMovie(){
  view.onShowLoading()

      val dataSource = Networkmodule.providesHttpAdapter(client = 
  OkHttpClient()).create(HomeDatasource::class.java)
      dataSource.discoverMovie().enqueue(object : Callback<HomeResponse> {
          override fun onResponse(call: Call<HomeResponse>, response: Response<HomeResponse>){
              view.onHideLoading()
              view.onResponse(((response.body()?.results ?: emptyList()) as List<Result<String>>))
      }
          override fun onFailure(call: Call<HomeResponse>, t:Throwable){
              view.onHideLoading()
              view.onFailure(t)
          }
      })
  }
}
```

I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two major problems here :

## Adapter instantiation

You do not need to re-instantiate the adapter each time you receive data.
Just instanciate it in the onCreate method with an empty list and update the list each time you have new data (don't forget to call notify method).

And attach the adapter to the recyclerView in the onCreate method as well

## Exemple

In your activity you need to :

- Declare and instantiate your Adapter as a class attribute.
- In the onCreate method attach it to the recyclerView
- On the onResponse method call a new method of your adapter called " update "

```kotlin
class HomeActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity(), HomeView {
@Inject
  lateinit var presenter: HomePresenter

  private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
  private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
  private val homeAdapter = HomeAdapter(emptyList())

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

      progressBar = findViewById(R.id.pb_home)
      recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_home)
      recyclerView.adapter = homeAdapter
      presenter.discoverMovie()
  }

  override fun onShowLoading() {
      progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
  }
  override fun onHideLoading() {
      progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
      recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
  }

  override fun onResponse(results: List<Result<String>>) {
      recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this@HomeActivity, 
  DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
      homeAdapter.update(results)
  }

  override fun onFailure(t:Throwable) {
      Log.e(HomeActivity::class.java.simpleName, "${t.printStackTrace()}")
  }
}
```

In your adapter :

- Make results a mutableList
- Create the update method

  - Clear the results list
  - Add your newResults list to your list
  - notifyDataSetChanged to redraw the list with new values

```kotlin
class HomeAdapter (private val results: MutableList<Result>): 
RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder>(){

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HomeViewHolder {
      return HomeViewHolder(
          LayoutInflater
              .from(parent.context).inflate(
                  R.layout.item_home,
                  parent,
                  false
              )
      )
  }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HomeViewHolder, position: Int){
      holder.bind()
  }
  override fun getItemCount(): Int{
      return results.count()
  }

  fun update(newResults: List<Result>) {
      results.apply {
         clear()
         addAll(newResults)
      }
      notifyDataSetChanged()

  }

  inner class HomeViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
      fun bind() {
          with(itemView) {
              val title = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.original_title)
              title.text

              val overview = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.overview)
              overview.text
          }
      }
  }
}
```

## Layout manager missing ?

We don't have your xml code so I don't know if you added the layoutManager on the xml like this (assuming you want a linearManager) :

```xml
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
```

You can do it programaticaly using the layoutManager attribute on the recyclerView :

```kotlin
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager()
```

You can set it in the onCreate method (if it is an activity) or onViewCreated (if it's a fragment) before attaching your adapter to the recyclerView

To avoid errors like that, the best way is to setup your recyclerView as soon as possible in the activity (onCreate) or fragment (onViewCreated) lifecycle.

Comment: What kind of .xml code do I need to fix at? And where do I apply this manager?

Comment: You can apply your LinearLayoutManager before setting your adapter in the onCreate method (if it is an activity) or onViewCreated (if it's a fragment)

You can also set the linearLayoutManager in the xml  like I said in my answer with app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
on the recyclerView xml tag

Comment: According to your xml file I see that you already have a LinearLayoutManager.

So, try toattach the adapter in the onCreate method (I will update the answer)

Comment: Where? HomeAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

This is my .xml files:

activity_home:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:context=".presentation.HomeActivity">

   <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@color/white"
       android:elevation="4dp"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:title="Belajar"
       app:titleTextColor="@color/black"/>

   <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/pb_home"
       style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:indeterminate="true"
       android:indeterminateTint="@color/black"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       tools:visibility="gone" />

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/rv_home"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
       android:scrollbars="vertical"

       app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       tools:listitem="@layout/item_home" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```